# Python connection failed with Mongo Atlas ( beginner problem)

Tags: python, mongodb

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import certifi
ca = certifi.where()
client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://sparta:test@cluster0.fuzltx4.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority', tlsCAFile=ca)

db = client.dbsparta
doc = {
    'name': '영수',
    'age': 24
}
db.users.insert_one(doc)
```

Hey guys I'm fresh new student to study coding.
I'm now kinda learned about Mongo DB things but I'm stuck here.
Unavaibled to connect my codes with Mongo Atlas collection.
Mongo Atlas didn't bring my data at all.

Need your help. L&P.

I did try to install all the drivers and version matched on my environment.

- install certifi but didn't help.

Comment: Maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470